# Seeking map API that allows pulling address range from polygon

Tags: coordinates, software-recommendations, excel, database, address

I've seen a lot of answers saying you can't draw polygons and get the exact addresses of all of the places contained; I don't need so much info.

I'm looking for a way to get a vague address range from within a set of coordinates. Say, draw a triangle and see that it encompasses..

2nd street, 120 - 280;

3rd street, 80 - 320;

4th street, 40 - 460;
and so on.

My goal (since there's probably a much simpler solution I'm not thinking of) is to be able to have a database of address ranges attributed to, say, municipalities in Excel. When typing an address in, a row could auto-populate applicable municipality name (or country, postal/zip code block, local sports league, school jurisdiction, whatever shapes you've defined) based on the range info.

A1"110" B1"3rd" C1"STREET" is within polygon: [Sheet2A1]"crazy ex, avoid" range at [Sheet2Betc.]'3rd street' <80, 320>.

D1 Populates with [Sheet2A1]